# Promise inside foreach loop in typescript, construct array from response and wait for all done

Tags: typescript, loops, foreach, promise

Im trying to iterate over an suites array that returned from http call then on each iteration have to call api to get points against each suite. Each call returned a promise and i have to construct an array and populate result from each api call response. I would like to return result array once everything within the suites.forEach loop is all done. But the current code retrun control after 1st suites.forEach occurance.

```
import Q = require("q");
public static getTestResults(testcaseId: number): Promise<TestResult[]>{
    
    let deferredPromise = Q.defer<TestResult[]>();
    let results: TestResult[] = [];

    let testManagementRestClient: TestManagementRestClient.TestHttpClient4_1;
    testManagementRestClient = TestManagementRestClient.getClient();
                 
      testManagementRestClient.getSuitesByTestCaseId(testcaseId).then(suites => {
            suites.forEach(suite => {
                testManagementRestClient.getPoints(suite.project.id, +suite.plan.id,
                                                    suite.id, undefined, undefined,
                                                    testcaseId.toString(), undefined,
                                                    true, undefined, undefined
                        ).then(points => {
                            points.forEach(point => {                            
                                    results.push(
                                        {
                                            projectId: suite.project.id,
                                            runId: point.lastTestRun.id,
                                            configuration: point.configuration.name
                                        }
                                    );
                            });
                            deferredPromise.resolve(results);
                        });  
            });
        });
    return deferredPromise.promise;
}
```

I googled and find out the $q.all() but didn't know how i can implement this on this specific scenario and if it resolve my issue.

Any advices would be welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for here is `Promise.all`. Assemble the calls to your rest endpoint as an array of tasks, something along the lines of:

`const tasks = suites.map(suite => testManagementRestClient.getPoints(...`

And then to wait for all those tasks to resolve, use `Promise.all` as follows:

`await Promise.all(tasks);`

You can find more about `Promise.all` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @Marcus is working fine. Here is another way to handle wait for all.

```
public static getTestResults(testcaseId: number): Promise<TestPoints[]> {
    let deferredPromise = Q.defer<TestPoints[]>();
    let results: TestPoints[] = [];
    let testManagementRestClient: TestManagementRestClient.TestHttpClient4_1;
    testManagementRestClient = TestManagementRestClient.getClient();
    testManagementRestClient.getSuitesByTestCaseId(testcaseId).then(async suites => {
        for (const suite of suites) {
            const points = await testManagementRestClient.getPoints(
                suite.project.id,
                +suite.plan.id,
                suite.id,
                undefined,
                undefined,
                testcaseId.toString(),
                undefined,
                true,
                undefined,
                undefined
            );
            points.forEach(point => {
                results.push(
                    {
                        projectId: suite.project.id,
                        runId: point.lastTestRun.id,
                        configuration: point.configuration.name + " (" + suite.name + ")"
                    }
                );
            });
        }
        deferredPromise.resolve(results);
    });
    return deferredPromise.promise;
}
```